# How to use form_widget in twig with FormBuilderInterface

Tags: twig, symfony4

When building a simple user creation form in Symfony with FormBuilderInterface and {{ form(form) }} my form is created as i defined it. While i need to add custom select boxes i need to create the form field manually. Therefor i tried to use e.g. {{ form_widget(form.firstname) }} but no input field is created.

```
 {{ form(form) }}
```

Working with rendered input fields.

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
     <div class="form-row">
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form_widget(form.firstname) }}
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form_widget(form.lastname) }}
         </div>
     </div>
  {{ form_end(form) }}
```

not rendering anything.
Configuration:

```
$builder
    ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [
        'label' => '',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Vorname'
            ]
         ])
    ->add('lastname', TextType::class, [
        'label' => '',
           'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Nachname'
           ]
        ]);
```

Any advice how to solve this or what do i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I have learnt to use the FormBuilderInterface (thank to GRAFIKART tutorial !)

#### FILE : src/Controller/Property.php

```
 class PropertyController extends AbstractController
 {   
  /**/
  public function __construct(PropertyRepository $repository, ObjectManager $em) {
        $this->repository = $repository; $this->em=$em;  }

 /**
 * @Route("/biens", name="property.index")
 * @return Response
 */
 public function index(PaginatorInterface $paginator, Request $request):Response
    {
        $search = new PropertySearch();
        $form = $this->createForm(PropertySearchType::class, $search);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $properties = $paginator->paginate($this->repository->findAllVisibleQuery($search),
         $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 9);

        return $this->render('property/index.html.twig', [
            'current_menu'=>'properties',
            'properties'=>$properties,
            'form' => $form->createView()
            ]);
 }
```

#### FILE : src/Form/PropertySearchType.php

```
class PropertySearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('minSurface', IntegerType::class, [
                'required' =>false,
                'label' =>false,
                'attr'=>['placeholder' => 'Surface minmale']  
            ])
           ->add('maxPrice', IntegerType::class, [
                'required' =>false,
                'label' =>false,
                'attr'=>['placeholder' => 'Prix maximal']  
            ])
           ->add('pOptions', EntityType::class,[
               'required'=>false,
               'label'=>false,
                'class'=>POption::class,
                'choice_label'=>'name',
                'multiple'=>true     
            ] );
        //->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' =>'Rechercher' ])
    }
```

And the corresponding twig-template file :

#### FILE : src/templates/property/index.html.twig

```
 <div   class="container">
 {{ form_start(form) }}
  <div class='form-row'>
   <div class='col'> {{ form_row(form.minSurface) }} </div>
   <div class='col'> {{ form_row(form.maxPrice) }} </div>
   <div class='col'> {{ form_row(form.pOptions) }} </div>
   <div class='col'>
     <button class='btn btn-primary'> Rechercher </button>
  </div>
  </div><!-- end row -->

{{ form_end(form) }}
  </div>
```

Comment: form_row or form_widget makes no difference, nothing outputs an input field. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Spooky is that if i make form_label(form.firstname) it outputs the label that i configured in the builder ...

Comment: SOLVED - I used {{form(form)}} before form_widget in template, that do not work. After removing form(form) it works!